# Non-homogeneous wave equation $u_{tt}=4u_{xx}+xt$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

How do I solve the following PDE using D'Alembert's formula? I cannot understand how to solve with term $xt.$ The Fourier is needless here.

The pde is the following:
\begin{align*}
u_{tt}&=4u_{xx}+xt\\
u(0,x)&=x^2\\
u_t(0,x)&=x.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the two PDEs

$u_{tt}-4u_{xx}=xt$, $u(0,x)=0$ ,$u_t(0,x)=0$ $(1)$

and

$u_{tt}-4u_{xx}=0$, $u(0,x)=x^2$, $u_t(0,x)=x$ $(2)$

Solve (2) using D'Alembert's formula. For (1)
use the transformation $\xi=x+2t,\eta=x-2t$ and reduce the problem to $u_{\xi\eta}=x(\xi,\eta)t(\xi,\eta)$. If $u_1$ is the solution of $(1)$ and $u_2$ is the solution of $(2)$ then $u_1+u_2$ will be the solution of your pde.